# Why does my code make the outcome a negative

Tags: javascript

So my code is bookmark code(Use in chrome) that I use for school and well this is it:

**javascript:**

```
var org=prompt("What is the original?"); 
var norg=prompt("What is the new?"); 
var x = +norg - +org; 
var y =+x / +org; alert(+y * -100);
//                         ^^^^^^
if (+org < +norg) {alert("Increase");} else {alert("Decrease");}
```

I used the -100 to make the outcome equal a positive percent but why does need the -100 to go to a positive?

Also if you were wondering this is to find the percent of change or trying to.

Comment: `* **-100**` is not valid Javascript. What is this code trying to do?

Comment: It seems like he is trying to tell the computer that he really really really wants to multiplicate by 100.

Comment: Remove all the plus signs, and if you always want to return a positive percentage use `Math.abs` -> **https://jsfiddle.net/rf16hskt/**

Comment: Note that Markdown doesn’t work in code blocks, so you can’t put `**`…`**` around parts of your code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try and attempt to answer this the best I can...

1) Remove all the plus signs. Refactor the code so the return value from `prompt` is casted as soon as it's assigned to the variable. Makes the code cleaner and less redundant, not to mention more performant.

```
var org = +(prompt("What is the original?"));
var norg = +(prompt("What is the new?"));
```

2) As @adeneo said, if you're looking for ensuring a positive value, wrap the values around `Math.abs`.

```
var y = Math.abs( x / org );
```

3) You also have an alert with invalid javascript `alert(+y * **-100**);`, which for now I'll comment out because it's a little unclear what you're trying to do.

Final code:

```
var org = +( prompt("What is the original?") );
var norg = +( prompt("What is the new?") );
var x = norg - org;
var y = Math.abs( x / org );
//alert(+y * **-100**); <-- commenting out for now
if ( org < norg ) {
    alert("Increase");
} else {
    alert("Decrease");
}
```

Comment: Yeah before I indented it I wanted it to be bolded and that is why there is the **...**

Comment: @Riderfighter if I have satisfied your question, please mark it as answered. Otherwise please add more information to your original question so that I can better try to answer it.